# Hyperledger Fabric chaincode fails to run and doesn't say why

Tags: typescript, hyperledger-fabric

While writing some chaincode I suddenly started getting this error:

> 2021-06-05T20:45:34.045Z - error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid
> responses from any peers. Errors:
> peer=peer1.local:7051, status=500, message=error in simulation: failed to execute transaction
> c33493ce22005d9e73b02e2b99d1d19daceb04f0ee9fb8fede0a3e1081ca9943:
> could not launch chaincode
> basic_1.0:32ca3f181f42e66b77c1026c31c92049336315143142535955a3f256d0249c18: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1

My code was working fine before and the TypeScript still compiles without error.

When checking the status with `docker logs ...` I see this:

> 2021-06-05 19:33:09.259 UTC [lifecycle] Work -> WARN 073 could not
> launch chaincode
> 'basic_1.0:5a649b5a8d084d83c86b02231ffa1b8e3e32e95f99de46e52588244fb9c99c59': chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1

How do I find out what the code error is?

Also, even though it fails to start the container the call to check if the chaincode has been installed successfully returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While digging around I noticed that the chaincode container was automatically stopping after failing to load. To find the crashed container, I used `docker ps -a`. When running `docker logs ...` on that one, or jumping inside the container with `docker run -it ... /bin/sh` I was able to get more information:

> ******** FAILED to run the application: Error: error in simulation: failed to execute transaction
> 6caf98016e71974a987a7f3a5295b518026c1f25ac117646db3dfcad89d179f7:
> could not launch chaincode
> basic_1.0:5a649b5a8d084d83c86b02231ffa1b8e3e32e95f99de46e52588244fb9c99c59: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1
>
> fabric-chaincode-node start --peer.address localhost:7051
> --chaincode-id-name mycc
>
> Options:   --help                                  Show help
> [boolean]   -v, --version                           Show version
> number  [boolean]   --peer.address  [string] [required]
> --grpc.max_send_message_length  [number] [default: -1]   --grpc.max_receive_message_length  [number] [default: -1]   --grpc.keepalive_time_ms  [number] [default: 110000]   --grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms  [number] [default: 110000]   --grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms  [number] [default: 20000]   --grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data  [number] [default: 0]   --grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls  [number] [default: 1]   --ssl-target-name-override  [string]   --chaincode-id-name  [string] [required]   --module-path  [string] [default: "/usr/local/src"]
>
> [MissingRefError: can't resolve reference Array from id
> SomeClass#] {   message: "can't resolve reference Array from
> id SomeClass#",   missingRef: 'Array',   missingSchema:
> 'Array' } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1

Unfortunately, this still is't very helpful because there are no missing references to `Array` in my code, and from what I can see online this error is thrown by a JSON validation library. It seems Hyperledger Fabric is doing something internally that is causing some conflicts.

I narrowed it down to this: Hyperledger Fabric TypeScript SDK will crash if you try to reference a static function or static variable from a class decorated with `@Object` within a class that inherits from `Contract`.

So for example, DO NOT do this:

```
@Object()
export class SomeClass {
    public static PREFIX: string = "TEST";
    ...
}
```

and then in a contract class:

```
export class SomeContract extends Contract {
    @Transaction()
    public async SomeFunction(ctx: Context): Promise<string> {
        return SomeClass.PREFIX;
}
```

Instead, refactor the static variables and functions from `SomeClass` to `SomeClassHelper` or some other file. When refactored this way, the exact same code works fine.